# AWS Lambda timeout on DynamoDB client.get_waiter

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have written a Python 3.7 Lambda function that creates a DynamoDB table, but it is timing out.  I am following [Creating a New Table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html) example:

```
import boto3
import json

def create_table():
    # Get the service resource.
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # Create the DynamoDB table.
    table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='users',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'username',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'last_name',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 2,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 2
    })

    # Wait until the table exists.
    table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='users')

    # Print out some data about the table.
    print("item_count:", table.item_count)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    create_table()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

When I run this from the AWS console with the Test button, I get a timeout error. I even set the time out to `9` seconds.  The `user` table still gets created even though this error occurs:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-11-17T02:34:00.007Z Task timed out after 9.00 seconds"
}
```

When I comment out this line, the function is successful:

```
table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='users')
```

What do I need to do to either not have a time out error or ensure the that the table has been created?

Comment: Add create table job to a try/catch block, then print out the error. I think the users table has never created. You can make sure that the user table is existed or not via aws console.

Comment: @hoangdv: I check the DynamoDB console, and the `user` table is in there

Answer (score 0):

By default the `wait` function [polls every 20 seconds](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Waiter.TableExists) until a successful state is reached but this can be changed.

I modified the code and now there are no timeout errors.  It takes about `7` seconds to create the table:

```
    table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='users',WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 1,
        'MaxAttempts': 30
    })
```